# 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "son.py", line 120, in <module>
    `main()`
  File "son.py", line 101, in main
    `temp += item`
TypeError: 'ApplyResult' object is not iterable
```

Code:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=int(args.process))
for i in range(int(args.process)):
    result_first_round.append(pool.apply_async(Son_Algorithm, (i,)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
first_temp = []
for res in result_first_round: 
    first_temp.append(res)
    #first_temp.append(res.get()) 


#Second Scan
result_final_round = []
temp = []
for item in first_temp:
    temp += item
temp2 = []
for result in temp:
    if not result in temp2:
        temp2.append(result)
temp_result = temp2
```

Comment: I added more detail, plz check

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to add the element `item` to the list `temp`. In that case you need to use the method `append()`, like this:

```
temp = []
for item in first_temp:
    temp.append(item)
```

The operator `+=` for a list only works if the second object is also a list (or at least an iterable).